# Power Apps - Is it possible to disable AutoSave when using Navigate(Patch(Defaults))?

Tags: powerapps-canvas

```
Navigate(
    Patch (
        'Item Canvas',
        Defaults('Item Canvas'),
        {
            Name: "Name Placeholder",
            Item: LookUp(
                'PR Lines',
                'PR Line No.' = PurchaseRequestLine.Selected.'PR Line No.'
            ),
            Vendor: "Vendor Placeholder",
            Amount: 0
        }
    )
)
```

This is my formula to navigate on a default create form of a record on Dynamics 365, one of the requirement is to not open on a new tab, hence, I used the Navigate() function instead of the Launch() function.

The only field that needs to be auto-populated is the Item lookup field, however, the other fields are required fields that is why I included them on the records to be updated, if not included, there is network patch error.

This formula is working fine, however, it is automatically saved upon clicking the button, the form should be Unsaved first.

This is my formula to navigate on a default create form of a record on Dynamics 365, one of the requirement is to not open on a new tab, hence, I used the Navigate() function instead of the Launch() function.

The only field that needs to be auto-populated is the Item lookup field, however, the other fields are required fields that is why I included them on the records to be updated, if not included, there is network patch error.

This formula is working fine, however, it is automatically saved upon clicking the button, the form should be Unsaved first.

Comment: Using `Patch()` creates a new record, avoid using it. If you want to maintain local copy before saving, use variable (record) in Power Apps